# Lettrine number overlapping with texts

Tags: lettrine, parallel-texts

Here i having an issue with the `lettrine` number with texts as it goes in overlapping , ussually the number `150` and the starting text should maintained by some distance, but here it goes on overlapping without maintaining the separation distance, here i am using `parallel` package to typeset the translation one language into english parallel, so here i used the `parallel` package, here left column is in another language(i.e Karbi), on right column is in English, Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[twoside,letterpaper]{book}
 \usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{hyphenat}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{lettrine}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 %\usepackage{fixltx2e}


 \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} %%% To restart footnote numbering on every new pages


 \newcommand{\jLChapter}[1]{\par\bigskip\lettrine{{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}{}\markboth{\chaplabel\ #1:1}{\chaplabel\ #1:1}\renewcommand{\jnumChapters}{#1}}


 \newcommand{\jverseFormat}[1]{#1}
 \newcommand{\jChapterNumFormat}[1]{\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}

 \newcommand{\jverse}[3]{\noindent{\jChapterNumFormat{#1}\markboth{\chaplabel\ \jnumChapters :#1}{\chaplabel\ \jnumChapters :#1}} #2{\jverseFormat{#3}}\par\smallskip\renewcommand{\jnumVerses}{#1}}

 \newcommand{\jBracketWord}[1]{\emph{#1}}

 \newcommand{\jParaSymbol}[0]{{}}

 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.0pt}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
 \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
 \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
 \addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}

 \newcommand{\chaplabel}{}
 \newcommand{\jnumChapters}{0}
 \newcommand{\jnumVerses}{0}
 \usepackage{parallel}

  \newcommand \prelude[1] {\makebox[9.4cm][l]{#1}} 


 \newcommand{\jRChapter}[1]{\lettrine[ante={\prelude{}}]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{}}




 \usepackage{titlesec}

 \titleformat{\chapter}
     {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
     {}
     {0pt}
     {}

 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*11.5}{*8}

 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

 \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


 \begin{document}
 \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}
 \frontmatter

 \title{The Holy Bible}
 \date{}
 \author{}
 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
 \maketitle
 %\renewcommand*\contentsname{The Old Testament}
 \tableofcontents
 \mainmatter
 \pagenumbering{gobble}

 \part*{The Old Testament}
 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.0pt}
 \renewcommand{\jnumChapters}{0}
 \pagenumbering{arabic} 
 \chapter{Genesis}
 \renewcommand{\chaplabel}{Kecheng}

 \begin{Parallel}{9.1cm}{9.1cm}

  \ParallelLText{\jverse{}{\jLChapter{150}}{}{Kechengsi, Arnam sining-heihei lapen pirthe kepinchong ahut, }}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{}{\jRChapter{150}}{}{In the beginning when God created the heavens and the earth, }}
  \ParallelPar
  \ParallelLText{\jverse{2}{}{pirthe arje avelang lapen thangnatta ave, lapen lang-lom athak kangtingsi dolang; lapen Arnam Akarjong lang-heihei athak damlo.  }}
  \ParallelRText{\jverse{2}{}{the earth was a formless void and darkness covered the face of the deep, while a wind from God swept over the face of the waters. }}
  \ParallelPar

 \end{Parallel}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features of `lettrine` don't seem to be used fully, in particular the dropcaps (second argument of `\lettrine`, which is left empty). Therefore a simpler approach could be used, that allows more control.

Here an attempt with `tabularx`. The idea is to make a table with the number on the left and the first paragraph on the right.

There are some spacing adjustments: the table padding is set to 0 with `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` to reduce the space on the left of the number, and a small space on the right of the number is added to compensate for the lack of colsep on this side. Furthermore the text on the right is shifted up a bit to align with the top of the number.

MWE (I have reduced the original code a bit):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{parallel}

\newcommand{\jverse}[2]{\noindent{\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{#1}}} {#2}\par\smallskip}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\newcommand{\printChapNum}[2]{%
\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{9.1cm}{lX}{%
\Huge\color{red} #1}\hspace{1mm} &%
\vspace{-6mm}#2\\
\end{tabularx}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}{9.1cm}{9.1cm}
\ParallelLText{\printChapNum{150}{Kechengsi, Arnam sining-heihei lapen pirthe kepinchong ahut,}}
\ParallelRText{\printChapNum{150}{In the beginning when God created the heavens and the earth,}}
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{\jverse{2}{pirthe arje avelang lapen thangnatta ave, lapen lang-lom athak kangtingsi dolang; lapen Arnam Akarjong lang-heihei athak damlo.}}
\ParallelRText{\jverse{2}{the earth was a formless void and darkness covered the face of the deep, while a wind from God swept over the face of the waters.}}
\ParallelPar

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]